# Using htmlAttributes for inserting an additional class to my link on my helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom html helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, object htmlAttributes)
{
     TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("a");
     builder.SetInnerText(linkText);
     builder.AddCssClass("dialogLink");
     return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

Sometimes I would like to add some html attributes to this anchor. For example, I would like to add an additional class to this link. I try this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, object htmlAttributes)
{
     TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("a");
     builder.SetInnerText(linkText);
     builder.AddCssClass("dialogLink");

     if (htmlAttributes != null)
         builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

     return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

**But it doesn't work because the class already exist (dialoglink).**

How can I proceed to be able to add more css to my link with htmlAttributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the `dialogLink` class after merging the attributes to avoid overriding it:

```
public static IHtmlString MyLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var builder = new TagBuilder("a");
    builder.SetInnerText(linkText);
    if (htmlAttributes != null)
    {
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }
    builder.AddCssClass("dialogLink");
    return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use

```
if (htmlAttributes != null) 
builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);
```

[link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493134%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
public void MergeAttribute(
    string key,
    string value,
    bool replaceExisting
)
```